# Cucumber failing in docker container because of bundler

Tags: ruby, docker, rubygems, cucumber, bundler

We have a cucumber/selenium regression pack which is written in ruby and runs using Rakefile. When I run regression pack locally on my machine, everything works fine. However we need this to be running in container so we can hook it up to our CI pipeline. Therefore we are building a docker container. I am building my docker image FROM ruby:2.3, then I run:

```
bundle install --without development test
```

Which works fine. All the dependencies from the Gemfile are installed. Including cucumber & selenium. Then I execute rake task to run Cucumber and I see this error:

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.3/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:373:in `block in replace_bin_path': can't find executable bundle (Gem::Exception)
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems.rb:278:in `activate_bin_path'
from /usr/local/bin/bundle:22:in `<main>'
```

And I don't know why as clearly bundler is install as I am using it to install all the dependencies and cucumber it self.

Anyone seen this before?

Update:

I found issue on GitHub reffering to very particular [incompability](https://github.com/docker-library/ruby/issues/73).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment as I mentioned in the update above ([link](https://github.com/docker-library/ruby/issues/73)) there is no great solution to this problem available however rolling back with:

```
gem update --system 2.6.1
gem install bundler --version $BUNDLER_VERSION
```

Solved my issue.